# Как тремя распилами распилить 2 бревна на требуемые кружки?

Tags: алгоритм

Задачка из школьной олимпиады. Как тремя распилами распилить 2 бревна на кружки по 1-му метру: одно длиной 4, другое 9 метров; После каждого распила (и перед первым распилом, естественно) можно ставить брёвна и их куски друг на друга. Может это невозможно?

Comment: Наверное, подразумевается, что кол-во 1м кружков должно быть максимально?

Comment: @gecube нет

Comment: @gecube в данном случае их должно быть 4+9=13 з.ы.Ваш Кэп

Comment: Ставить куски друг на друга.

Comment: У меня больше 10 не получается =(

Comment: @igumnov можно конкретнее?

Comment: 11 я сделал пока и один двухметровый

Comment: Что за кружки? Это что такое? Имеется ввиду чурки?

Comment: 12 СРАЗУ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ, НО ЕЩЁ 1 НУ НИКАК)) НАВЕРНОЕ Я ПОТУТПЕЛ)))

Comment: 12 - просто

    1)
      --|--
    ----|-----
    2)
       -|-
       -|-
      --|--
      --|---
    3) 4 уже есть
       -|-
       -|-
       -|-
       -|--

вот 11 метровых и 1 2-хметровый

Comment: Да мой вариант такой же как у @Spectre.

Comment: а бревно может быть U-образным?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Непонятно, причем тут программирование. На [Математике](http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/4099/%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8) обсуждался более сложный вопрос (двумерный случай). Там же разобран и одномерный случай.

В предложенном варианте (4 и 9 м) первое бревно не важно (его можно приложить к второму). За 3 разреза можно получить максимально 2^3 = 8 частей, а нам нужно 9. Задача не имеет решения.

Comment: Задача имеет решение.  
Сравните с этой задачей:  
http://www.braingames.ru/?path=comments&puzzle=238
там нужно распилить на 7 частей за 2 распила.  
Я правда не нашел решения этой задачи, но оно скорее всего есть. На этом сайте еще не встретил загадки с ответом «нет решения». Просто надо мыслить объемно и выпукло :-)
Можете кстати погуглить ответ к загадке с БрэйнГеймс, потом по аналогичному алгоритму решить эту.

Comment: Нет, там не нужно пилить на 7 частей, ведь при оплате можно _брать сдачу_. Это известная задача (надо распилить на части длиной 1, 2 и 4 седьмых).  
А в Вашей задаче, если не предполагать какую-нибудь игру слов или другую хитрость, решение такое: за каждый распил можно увеличить число кусков максимум вдвое. Если, конечно, не "загибать" бревна. Поэтому из 1 бревна длиной 9 можно получить максимум 8 кусков.

Comment: в принципе да, если распилить на 1, 2 и 4, то можно устроить, что если рабочий будет отдавать зарплату за прошлый день, то ему можно выдать новую зарплату.
Попробую запостить такой ответ :-)

Comment: На том сайте? Я уже ответила )))  
А пользоваться чужими ответами нехорошо! ((

Comment: Тогда не буду постить :-)
Тоже люблю честно отвечать на том сайте только свои ответы :-)

Answer (score 3):

У нас целая группа работала над этим вопросом, в итоге пришли к выводу, что за 3 распила невозможно распилить 9-ти метровое бревно по метру, обязательно останется кусок 2 метра длиной

Comment: Если бы этот вопрос был на Математике, Вас бы попросили доказать. Впрочем, доказательство очень простое (см. мой ответ). Знание его освобождает "целую группу" от непродуктивной работы. )))

Comment: Да ладно, нам поработать не влом) тем более заняться было нечем)

Answer (score 1):

1 распил: 4 = 2 и 2, 9 = 5 и 4
2 распил: 2 и 2 = 1 1 1 1, 5 и 4 = 2 3 2 2
3 распил: 5 и 4 = 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1
в итоге 12 бревен)) как сделать 13, это походу для меня нерешаемая задача...